# maximality of an ultrafilter

Tags: general-topology, filters

> Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a filter on a set $I$. Prove that $\mathscr{F}$ is an ultrafilter if and only if there does not exist any filter $\mathscr{F^*}$ on $I$ such that $\mathscr{F^*} \supsetneq \mathscr{F}$.
>
> Proof: Let $\mathscr{F}$ be an ultrafilter and suppose there exist a filter $\mathscr{F^*}$ on $I$ such that $\mathscr{F^*} \supsetneq \mathscr{F}$. Then by definition of an ultrafilter, for each $E \subset I$, either $E \in \mathscr{F}$ or $I \setminus E \in \mathscr{F}$. But that would imply that for each $E \subset I$, either $E \in \mathscr{F^*}$ or $I \setminus E \in \mathscr{F^*}$ which implies $\mathscr{F^*}$ is an ultrafilter.

I am stuck after this. I was going to conclude that an ultrafilter cannot contain an ultrafilter but I can't find anything that proves my statement.  Is this case or can an Ultrafilter on a set $I$ contain another ultrafilter on the set $I$?

I am also having a really hard time proving the other direction.

Edit:

Okay I was pointed to some questions similar to this and I am still a little confused. So from what I read I should conclude that this contradicts the maximality of ultrafilters, but I am trying to prove maximality so why can I use this?

I'm also still confused how to start the other direction?

Comment: You can't immediately jump from "for each $E\subset I$ either $E$ or $E^c$ in $\mathscr{F}$" to for *each* $E\subset I$ both $E$ and $E^c$ in $\mathscr{F}^*$.  What you can say is that for *some* $E\subset I$ both $E$ and $E^c$ in $\mathscr{F}^*$.  Then $\mathscr{F}^*$ contains $E\cap E^c=\varnothing$ which is forbidden by the definition a filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $E\in\mathscr{F}^*\setminus\mathscr{F}$. Then in particular $E\notin\mathscr{F}$, so $I\setminus E\in\mathscr{F}$. And $\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{F}^*$, so $I\setminus E\in\mathscr{F}^*$. But $E\cap(I\setminus E)=\varnothing$, so $\varnothing\in\mathscr{F}^*$, which is impossible.

Comment: I am really confused about the other direction. If I assume there exists (or doesnt exist) $\mathscr{F^*}$ on I such that $\mathscr{F^*} \supsetneq \mathscr{F}$ I don't see where I would go from there? Do I need to assume somthing about $\mathscr{F}$ ?

Comment: @Kim: You mean proving that if $\mathscr{F}$ is a maximal filter on $I$, then it’s an ultrafilter? Prove the contrapositive: show that if $\mathscr{F}$ is not an ultrafilter, then there is a filter $\mathscr{F}^*$ that properly contains it. HINT: If it’s not an ultrafilter, there is some $E\subseteq I$ such that neither $E$ nor $I\setminus E$ is in $\mathscr{F}$; show that one of these sets can be added to $\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: I am not sure how to show one of these sets is added to $\mathscr{F}$. Also, once I show that, how will this lead to showing there is a filter $\mathscr{F}^{*}$ that contains it. Is it by the way we add one of these to $\mathscr{F}$. In other words, is the only way one of these can be added to $\mathscr{F}$ is if $\mathscr{F}$ is contained in some $\mathscr{F}^{*}$?

Comment: @Kim: If $E\cap F\ne\varnothing$ for each $F\in\mathscr{F}$, then $\mathscr{F}\cup\{E\}$ is a filter base, meaning that if you close it under supersets, you have a filter $\mathscr{F}^*$ that properly contains $\mathscr{F}$. Similarly, if $(I\setminus E)\cap F\ne\varnothing$ for each $F\in\mathscr{F}$, then $\mathscr{F}\cup\{I\setminus E\}$ is a base for a filter that properly contains $\mathscr{F}$. If neither of these is the case, there must be $F_0,F_1\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $$E\cap F_0=\varnothing=(I\setminus E)\cap F_1\,.$$ What does this say about $F_0\cap F_1$?

Answer (score 0):

Your quoted "proof" is no proof at all. It even starts out wrong.
Suppose $\mathscr{F}$ is an ultrafilter, i.e.

$$\forall E \subseteq I: E \in \mathscr{F} \text{ or } I\setminus E \in \mathscr{F}\tag{1}$$

We want to prove that there is no filter $\mathscr{F}^\ast$ such that $\mathscr{F}^\ast \supsetneq \mathscr{F}$. so suppose $\mathscr{F}^\ast$ would be such a filter. As we have a proper inclusion of families of subsets, there must be *some* $ E \subseteq I$ such that $E \in \mathscr{F}^\ast$ and $E \notin \mathscr{F}$. That last fact, combined with $(1)$, which we know for $\mathscr{F}$, we conclude that $I \setminus E \in \mathscr{F}$ (the other option is explicitly ruled out after all).
As $\mathscr{F} \subseteq \mathscr{F}^\ast$ we also have $I\setminus E \in \mathscr{F}^\ast$. But then $\emptyset = E\cap (I\setminus E) \in \mathscr{F}^\ast$ as filters are closed under intersections, but this is a contradiction as $\emptyset$ is not allowed to be a member of a filter.

So the assumption of the proper inclusion leads to a contradiction, so $\mathscr{F}^\ast$ cannot exist. QED